# Indesign script to add/change text in a paragraph

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, indesign-scripting

There's a particular paragraph in my document and I want to replace its content completely with something else programatically. Is there any function to do this? I need something like this:

> app.activeDocument.stories[7].paragraphs[0]. = "blah blah
>   blah";

where `<function>` is the function that would allow you to replace the content of the paragraph in question to "blah blah blah." I bet this is possible but am not aware of the functions available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be like this:

```
app.activeDocument.stories[7].paragraphs[0].contents = "blah blah blah\r";
```

See http://yearbookmachine.github.io/esdocs/#/InDesign/Paragraph/contents.

The `\r` creates a had linebreak. For a soft linebreak use `\n`